# how to stop storing null values in database every time when user refresh the browser in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i created one form in my application..so every time when user refreshes the browser..the form null values stored in database..and as well as mail also will send to particular person every time when refresh the browser..

Here is my view:

```
<form action="" id="form" method="post" >

  <div class="form-group">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="selection">
        <option>Telephonic</option>
        <option>F2F</option>
        <option>HR</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="box-body pad">
      <label>Comments</label>
      <textarea class="textarea" name="comments"  id="Comments "placeholder="Place comments here" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="box-body pad">
      <label>Results</label>
      <textarea class="textarea" name="results" placeholder="Place results here" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="selection_process" value="1" class="flat-red" checked>Selected
      </label>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="selection_process" value="2" class="flat-red">Not Selected
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="checkbox icheck">

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</form>
```

This is my controller:

```
<?php
public function add_selection()
{
  $data=array(
    'selection'=>$this->input->post('selection'),
    'comments'=>$this->input->post('comments'),
    'results'=>$this->input->post('results'),
    'selection_process'=>$this->input->post('selection_process')
    );

  if($data['selection_process']==1)
  {
    $config = Array(
      'protocol' => 'smtp',
      'smtp_host' => 'ssl://md-in-42.webhostbox.net',
      'smtp_port' => 465,
      'smtp_user' => 'test3@clozloop.com',
      'smtp_pass' => 'test3'
      );
    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $this->email->from('test3@clozloop.com', 'bharathi');
    $list=array('nalamalapu.bharathi@gmail.com','bharathi.nalamalapu@gmail.com');
    $this->email->to($list);
    $this->email->subject('YOU ARE SELECTED');
    $link = 'Click on this link - <a href="http://localhost/job_portal/index.php/Login/signin">Click Here</a>';
    $this->email->message($link);
    $this->email->send();
  }
  else
  {
    $config = Array(
      'protocol' => 'smtp',
      'smtp_host' => 'ssl://md-in-42.webhostbox.net',
      'smtp_port' => 465,
      'smtp_user' => 'test3@clozloop.com',
      'smtp_pass' => 'test3'
      );
    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $this->email->from('test3@clozloop.com', 'bharathi');
    $list=array('nalamalapu.bharathi@gmail.com','bharathi.nalamalapu@gmail.com','mounikavemula537@gmail.com');
    $this->email->to($list);
    $this->email->subject('YOU ARE NOT SELECTED');
    $link = 'Click on this link - <a href="http://localhost/job_portal/index.php/Login/signin">Click Here</a>';
    $this->email->message($link);
    $this->email->send();
  }
  $this->SelectionModel->add_selection_details($data);
  $this->load->view('selection/selection_details',$data);
}
?>
```

please help me how to  do this..
Thank You..

Comment: use form validation

Comment: ya i used form validation also..but it's working only when user click on submit only..it's working..it's not working for browser refresh..

Comment: <script>
function validateMyForm() 
{
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["comments"].value;
    if (x == "") 
    {
        alert("comments must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

     var x = document.forms["myForm"]["results"].value;
    if (x == "") 
    {
        alert("results must be filled out");
        return false;

    }
   
 }

</script>

Comment: you  mean ajax validation..i have no idea on ajax validation..please show me how to use ajax..

Comment: i mean ajax request, you can also add 
 required="" filed in your html code

Comment: but that is not working..i tried that one also..my problem is user refresh the page using browser refresh button..at that time null values stored in my database

Comment: try in your textarea section

Comment: i can't understand..can you please explain properly..

Comment: <textarea class="textarea" name="comments" required=""  id="Comments "placeholder="Place comments here" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>

Comment: no..it's not working..again stored null values in database..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution..
Change your controller and model code like this..

Controller:

```
public function add_selection()
```

{

```
$data["msg"]="";
 $this->load->model('SelectionModel');
$data['rolename']=$this->SelectionModel->getrolename();
$data['candidate']=$this->SelectionModel->getcandidates();
$data['usertype']=$this->SelectionModel->getusers();
$data['companyname']=$this->SelectionModel->getcompanyname();
```

if($this->input->post())
  {

```
 $this->SelectionModel->add_selection_details($this->input->post());
 $all_users = $this->input->post('user_id');
 print_r($all_users);
       foreach($all_users as $key)
      {
         $get_email = $this->SelectionModel->get_user_email_by_id($key);

         $config = Array(
          'protocol' => 'smtp',
          'smtp_host' => 'ssl://md-in-42.webhostbox.net',
          'smtp_port' => 465,
          'smtp_user' => 'test3@clozloop.com',
          'smtp_pass' => 'test3'
      );
         $this->load->library('email',$config);
         $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
         $this->email->from('test3@clozloop.com', 'bharathi');
         $this->email->to($get_email);
          $this->email->cc('bharathi.nalamalapu@gmail.com'); 
          $this->email->bcc('nalamalapu.bharathi@gmail.com');
         $this->email->subject('this is our candidate details pls go through it');
         $link = 'Click on this link - <a href="http://localhost/job_portal/index.php/Login/signin">Click Here</a>';
         $this->email->message($link);
         print_r($get_email);
         if($this->email->send())
          {

              echo "email sent";
          }
          else
          {
              echo "email failed";

           }

     }
```

}

$this->load->view('selection/selection_details',$data);
}

Model:

```
function add_selection_details($post='')
```

{

```
  $data=array(
          'selection_id'=>$this->input->post('selection_id'),
          'comments'=>$this->input->post('comments'),
          'results'=>$this->input->post('results'),
        'role_id'=>$this->input->post('role_id'),
        'candidate_id'=>$this->input->post('candidate_id'),
         'company_id'=>$this->input->post('company_id'),
        'user_id'=> implode(',',$this->input->post('user_id'))
          // 'selection_process'=>$this->input->post('selection_process')

        );
   $this->db->insert('selection', $data);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Give form action controller/functionName

change this line to

```
 <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Submit</button>
```

to

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" value="submit"/>
```

and in controller add this condition

```
 public function add_selection()
 {  
if($this->input->post('submit') && $this->input->post('submit') =='submit'){
//rest of ur code
}
}
```

or else use form validation to check form is valid or not
after this redirect to page or reload the page

Comment: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) i got this error when i tried this code in my controller

Comment: please check this code after removing isset .. isset() is used to check variable esixts

Answer (score 0):

The issue with using POST data is that on refresh the browser will resend the POST information, this is why many people use js/ajax to send this kind of thing.. I would suggest looking at how to do it by this method or builing into your code validation at both the controller and the model to ensure no nulls (unset variables) are allowed.

Having the page post back on itself is an okay method of doing this.

```
<form action="[insert the method/view here]" id="form" method="post" >
```